# How to only show the straight measurement using the measurement extension in the 3D Viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am making an application that uses the measurement extension and the 3D viewer. When users take 3D measurements, I only want to show the straight measurement - currently it is also showing the x and y measurement. Is this possible?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VwfL5.png)

The viewer is showing up correctly, however I would like to know if there is a way to not show the 'x' and 'y' measurements

Thank you for your help!